# How to host a normal Web Service not WCF in IIS using Console

Tags: .net

Is there any way that I can host a Web Service in IIS from my C# code?

Thanx

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: "in IIS using Console" seems to be contradictory - you can host a WCF service in IIS, WAS or using your own Process Host service.

Comment: What is "not normal" about WCF web services?!?!??

Answer (score 0):

I have written a couple of web apps that use web services. If you just want the web service installed in IIS with the web application installer you can just create a web installer project within the solution and add the project output from the web service and this should get installed along side the web site.